# is it possible to use lwc properties in Salesforce experience cloud components like Rich Content Editor

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc, salesforce-communities

I've created a lwc that returns a url. I'd like to use the value of that property to create url in a rich content editor. I thought that i might be able to use something like {!absoluteUrl} to access the property, but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Here is my .js file code from the lwc

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from "lwc";

import getAbsoluteUrl from "@salesforce/apex/AbsoluteUrlCmpController.getAbsoluteUrl";

 

export default class AbsoluteUrlCmp extends LightningElement {

  @wire(getAbsoluteUrl) absoluteUrl;

  @api absoluteUrl;

 }
```

Thanks!